# How to avoid Uri encoding using Uri.https from Dart library

Tags: http, dart

I've this snippet to access a rest service. But the method Uri.https are undesirable encoding the url resulting in:

```
https://unogs-unogs-v1.p.mashape.com/aaapi.cgi?query=new%3A7-%211900%2C2018-%210%2C5-%210%2C10-%210-%21Any-%21Any-%21Any-%21gt100-%21Yes&type=ns&st=adv&orderBy=Relevance&andOr=and
```

I want to let Url as is: `'new:7-!1900,2018-!0,5-!0,10-!0-!Any-!Any-!Any-!gt100-!Yes'`

In Retrofit/Kotlin I simply put `encoded=false` to Query parameter: `@Query("q", encoded = true)`

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class FetchMovies {
  final queryParameters = {
    'query': 'new:7-!1900,2018-!0,5-!0,10-!0-!Any-!Any-!Any-!gt100-!Yes',
    'type': 'ns',
    'st': 'adv',
    'orderBy': "Relevance",
    'andOr': 'and'
  };

  Future<http.Response> execute() async {
    var uri = Uri.https(
        'unogs-unogs-v1.p.mashape.com', '/aaapi.cgi', queryParameters, );
    print(uri.toString());


    return await http.get(uri, headers: {
      'X-Mashape-Key': '',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you add that portion to the unencodedPath:

```
'/aaapi.cgi' + '?new:7-!1900,2018-!0,5-!0,10-!0-!Any-!Any-!Any-!gt100-!Yes'
```

And then also remove it from the Map.

Answer (score 1):

Even that adding the query portion to `unencodedPath` will solve the problem, this way I would have to get rid of `queryParameters` and would have to build the query string in dynamic way. The best solution I've found was use the `decodeComponent` utility method from Uri class:

```
return await http.get(Uri.decodeComponent(uri.toString()), headers: {
  'X-Mashape-Key': '',
  'Accept': 'application/json'
});
```